# Braintree iOS SDK: How to add a card

Tags: ios, braintree

I am new to Braintree. I have configured Drop-in UI and used for making payment via credit card and pay pal. But I am unable to figure out how to add a new credit card screen. I have attached an image for an explanation. If anyone has done that kindly guide me in the right direction.[image]

Comment: You need custom add card screen ?

Answer (score 2):

I work at Braintree. Feel free to reach out to support@braintreepayments.com with any further questions.

The Braintree DropIn UI depends upon [generating a client token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate). If you generate a client token with a customer ID from your Braintree account, the DropIn UI will automatically display the customer's saved payment methods, as seen in that third image.

If you click on the + sign you circled, it will display the standard credit card UI you see in the first picture.

If the customer does not have saved payment methods, it will display the standard UI and the payment method will be added to that customer's record in Braintree.

Comment: I am unable to get the rightmost screen using the drop in UI code. I have no issue with client token part and first two screens appear and I have made a successful transaction as well. How am i supposed to get the right most screen (coding point of view). I know the functionality of third screen as well, but I am unable to figure out how to show this screen in the app

Comment: I have already sent an email to support email address. Waiting for their response...

Comment: On your server side code, are you generating the client token using this code (this is ruby, the docs have other languages)?
@client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate(
  :customer_id => a_customer_id
)

Once you see the DropIn UI, click "Change Payment Method".

Comment: @user3775396 I am experiencing a similar issue, the rightmost screen only has the default card, no ability to add new cards

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a code to show default custom UI provide by BrainTree (BTUICardFormView)**

1) Create UIView in storyboard and give class (BTUICardFormView) and IBOutlet **BTUICardFormView**

```
import Braintree

@IBOutlet weak var cardForm: BTUICardFormView!
```

2) On button click you can get required value

```
@IBAction func saveContinueAction(_ sender: Any) {
        print("number :: \(cardForm.number)\n")
        print("expirationMonth ::\(cardForm.expirationMonth)\n")
        print("expirationYear ::\(cardForm.expirationYear)\n")
        print("cvv :: \(cardForm.cvv)\n")
    }
```

[image: Default UI provider by Braintree for add card]